# Group of kids get sucked into an Arthurian video game. Protagonist may have been called 'Lance'

Tags: story-identification, books

I once read a book about these group of kids who get sucked into a video game (I think). It was based on King Arthur and the Knights of the Round Table, as they each had their role there.

I think there was magic, and one of the kids may have been called Lance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: It's not a book but your description sounds like King Arthur and the Knights of Justice which came out in 1992. It has magic, a character named Lance, and the premise is that a football team travels back in time to replace King Arthur and his knights (each player corresponding to a specific knight).


Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur_and_the_Knights_of_Justice

Comment: @just_happen_to_know - There was also a comic book based on the series.